# Meaning of 'upon which'

Tags: expressions, time

I am not a native English speaker. I read this phrase in a book, '... more beloved than everything UPON WHICH the sun rises,...'
Could anyone clarify what this phrase means? And what is the meaning of 'upon which' here? Thanks

Comment: A modern version of that quote would be "More beloved than everything the sun shines on" (The author is saying that this thing is more important than everything in the whole world). This is form of english is rarely used now but it's essentially a reordering of "everything the sun shines upon".

Comment: It's always better to provide *context* (i.e. the surrounding passage) when asking what something means.  But I agree with Rathony.

Answer (score -1):

upon (up + on) which the sun rises... the word "upon" in this case, it is similar to the word "over".. upon seems a little bit more formal for me..

Even the Oxford website gives that notion: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/upon

"More formal term for on, especially in abstract senses. it was based upon two principles a school’s dependence upon parental support"

Think about all the things that are illuminated by the light of the rising sun (sun OVER everything).

For me, this phrase is very poetic and basically, means "something which is more beloved than everything".

Comment: This is not an explanation of the usage of _upon which_ in the question, which has nothing to do with being illuminated by the rising sun.